# Function of two variables as a function of a function

Tags: terminology, functions

Consider a function $f : \mathcal X \times \mathcal Y \mapsto \mathbb R$. I want to define $g_x(y) = f(x,y) : \mathcal Y \mapsto \mathbb R$. I want to say that

> $g_x$ is a ***_*__** of function $f$.

What is the appropriate word for ***_*____**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen your $g_x$ called the $x$-**section** of $f$.  E.g. Folland's *Real Analysis*, section 2.5.

Edit: Another notation that's often useful is to write $f(x, \cdot)$ instead of $g_x$.

Comment: Thanks. I have been using your latter suggestion $f(x, \cdot)$ so far, but it gets unwieldy to use that every time. The term $x$-section sounds much better. I will check the exact definition in Folland's book.

Answer (score 6):

This is sometimes called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).  It is closely related to the notion of an [exponential object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object).  But you don't really need to use either of these terms to perform this construction.

**Edit:**  Ah, I was assuming you were varying $x$.  If $x$ is fixed, you might want to call $g_x$ a [restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Restrictions_and_extensions) of $f$.

Comment: Thanks. In what I am looking at $x$ does vary, so currying is the right notion. However, I am afraid of going to category theory (a fearsome beast for the intended audience) for something this elementary

Comment: @Random User: It's also a widely used operation in functional programming in computer science -- but I don't know if that would be familiar to your intended audience either.